# Is it possible to put a character ( * ) in the 2 D array declared as int a[10][10]?

Tags: c

or is it possible to print given pattern by using 2D array,
n=4.

```
     432* 
     43*1
     4*21
     *321
```

Comment: The title asks about 2D int arrays being useable inn a certain way. The body asks an almost unrelated question. Please check whether you are describing an XY problemm. Also, please show your attempts at coding. I.e. get a HelloWorld running and then modify it as best as you can to get close to your goal. That serves to help us judge your level of knowledge. If that is already beyond you then you are basically asking for a basic C tutorial, which I am sorry to say, is off-topic here.

Comment: Would an answer be helpful which just uses loops to make the desired output, but no array whatsoever?

Comment: Your question could be improved with the help of the info found in the [tour] (Yes, I know you already took the tour, consider doing that again.), [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ Also, formatting questions correctly seems to be of a trouble for you, so have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Post the code you are having problems with.

Comment: (a) Arrays of `int` store only `int` values. There is no provision for storing a non-integer in an `int`. (b) You can accomplish this in various ways, such as choosing one `int` value that you will never use as an `int` and using it as if it represented your `*`. You would then have to customize your code that uses the array to recognize this value and handle it specially. (c) There are also entirely different ways of printing patterns without storing special values in an array. If you describe your overall problem more fully, people could advise you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to put a character ( * ) in the 2 D array declared as int a[10][10

Yes and no

**Yes, how?**
Using char array

```
char nArray[10][10];

int i = 0;
for (; i < 10; ++i)
    nArray[i][i] = '*';
```

Than if you want to convert char to int you could easily do it.

**No**, if you want to use `int` array. But there are ways around it.

```
int nArray[10][10];

int i = 0;
for (; i < 10; ++i)
    nArray[i][i] = '-1';
```

and when you print this you use something like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < 10; ++i) {
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < 10; ++j) {
        if (nArray[i][j] == -1)
           printf ("*")
        else
           printf ("%d", nArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```